# How to script check-in associated with a TFS item, just like Visual Studio does?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

In Visual Studio we have a TFS policy that every check-in must be associated with a work item.

How can I replicate that behavior in command line?

I prefer using just the tf.exe command, but using tfpt.exe is OK too. Finally, using TFS API is acceptable too.